# Data not displaying without model null check..Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC4 Razor

Controller--

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult FillLogin(LoginModel model)
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (model.username == "password")
                    {
                        string x = model.getdata();
                        model.field1= "Hello";
                        return View(model);
                    }
                }
                return View(model);
            }
```

In view i am not getting the Data Displayed when  i tried like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.field1)
```

But working Fine if Given like

```
 @if (Model != null )
       {            
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.field1)
       }
```

Can anyone help me why this happens....I am new to MVC

Answer (score 0):

Model should never be null. And I suspect that the problem is in the GET action not in the POST one. ALWAYS return a new instance of the model

```
public ActionResult FillLogin()
{
      return View(new LoginModel());
}
```